# JAXB is confused about root elements?

Tags: java, jaxb, visio

I'm trying to marshal a file using the [Visio XML Schema](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=23976), which consists of 3 schema files and produces three packages when java source is generated with XJC:

- com.microsoft.schemas.visio._2003.core
- com.microsoft.schemas.visio._2006.extension
- com.microsoft.schemas.office.visio._2010.extension

The root element is `VisioDocument`, and all of the classes I'm using are in the `2003` package.

Here is my approach to marshalling my XML file:

```
VisioDocumentType visioDoc = new VisioDocumentType();
... manipulated here ...
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.microsoft.schemas.visio._2003.core");
Marshaller m = jc.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
m.marshal(new JAXBElement<VisioDocumentType>(new QName("uri","local"), VisioDocumentType.class, visioDoc), bw);
```

When executed, I receive this error:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "com.microsoft.schemas.visio._2003.core.PagePropsType" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

I am using `PagePropsType`, but it is not a root element. Why does JAXB think it is?

Comment: How is the property you are setting the instance of `com.microsoft.schemas.visio._2003.core.PagePropsType` on annotated?

Comment: `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PageProps_Type", propOrder = {
    "pageWidthOrPageHeightOrShdwOffsetX"
})` Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I meant the property you are setting the instance onto and not the `PagePropsType` itself.

Comment: Here is the object I'm adding it to: http://snipt.org/qKT3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem resides in the `... manipulated here ...` part of your code.

Based on the assumption that you do the following (or something similar).

```
// you create a page prop
PagePropsType pageProps = ...

// then you feed it to a shape sheet
ShapeSheetType shapeSheet = ...
shapeSheet.getTextOrXFormOrLine().add(pageProps);
```

<sub>(`ShapeSheetType` is a superclass for `StyleSheetType`, et cetera.)</sub>

If this's the case, then your problem lies in adding the `pageProps` to the list directly.

If you take a look at the `getTextOrXFormOrLine()` method's documentation it lists what kind of types the list can hold. Every type is wrapped in a `JAXBElement<...>` so you have to wrap `pageProps` before adding it to the list.

You should do it like this:

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
JAXBElement<PagePropsType> pagePropsElement = objectFactory.createShapeSheetTypePageProps(pageProps);
```

<sub>(Note that I've used XJC 2.2.4 to compile the schemas; for me every class' name is suffixed with `Type`. Maybe this is why I ended up with `VisioDocumentType` instead of `VisioDocument` like you, but it shouldn't matter.)</sub>

Comment: This appears to be what I was missing, thanks. (the lack of `Type` was a typo)

Answer (score 1):

If you check your generated code, you will find a `ObjectFactory` class in there. This class should have a method that returns a `VisioDocument` wrapped in a `JAXBElement`, and that it the object that you want to pass to the marshaller.

Same applicable to all objects you set inside `VisioDocument` - don't create them with '`new`' but use `ObjectFactory`.

Comment: I did this but the problems remains.

Comment: _Same applicable to all objects you set inside VisioDocument - don't create them with 'new' but use ObjectFactory._ In my opinion `ObjectFactory` should and have to be used _only_ if one have to create a type wrapped in `JAXBElement<...>`, otherwise it just pollutes the code. Methods like `createXxxType` in `ObjectFactory` only calls `new XxxType()` anyway.